# Django Pagination, User selected entry amount error

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-queryset

I have a page with a form that a user enters information to help filter a queryset when they press submit. Upon submission, they are brought to a results page that displays this filtered queryset. I have pagination set up with Django as well as an interactive drop down where the user can select how many entries of the queryset they would like to view per page. I got all this working, but the issue that I am having is that to make it work I need a global queryset object. I've run into issues when several threads are using the page at once so I am trying to find alternative options than using a global, but still allowing the interactive dropdown and pagination.

When I try to remove the global and click on the second or another subsequent page, the query seems to get wiped out and I get an error saying a None object cannot be iterated over. Any tips on alternatives I can try that will avoid this error? Thanks!

Comment: You **definitely don't** want a global queryset; if you had one, all users would see the same one. But there's no need for one; you already have all the information needed to recreate the query in each request. If you want any more specific help, you'll need to post the code you're using and the errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about it wrong - rather than trying to remember the state of the queryset for each user and paging based on that, instead set your user page up to request the page it wants and request it from the server.

You could do this in a lot of ways, but something like Tastypie or django rest framework can give you an easy way to develop a page based api and Datatables or similar can allow you to filter and request the pages using Ajax.